# Can a string hold a newline character if given from a char type?

Tags: c++, string, stl, io, std

What I mean is this. Say we read from standard input a bunch of text, and one by one we read it into a character type. If one of these characters is a newline, obviously this variable can hold information about the new line. What if I push this character into a string stream, and then output the contents of the string stream into a string?

It appears that this new string doesn't hold any data about the newline character.

Is there anyway to have the string keep this information?

Code snippet:

```
    stringstream ssChar;
    unsigned char aChar;
    string strChar;

    sourceFile >> noskipws >> aChar;
    ssChar << aChar;
    getline(ssChar, strChar);
    //ssChar.str("");
    //ssChar.seekg(0);
    cout << "Next char is: " << (int)aChar << endl;
    cout << "Length of char(from stringstream): " << strChar.length() << endl;
```

Input: file with a newline
xxd sourceFile

0000000: 0a0a (2 newlines actually)                                     ..

Output:
Next char is: 10 (ascii newline)
Length of char: 0 (str is empty however)

Comment: you need to show code, some things will eat newline characters

Comment: Could you provide an sscce of what you've tried?

Comment: Edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Of course the string will store character data passed into it. There is probably some formatting operation in your code which is eating whitespace or newlines.

Comment: What about the concatenation of one string with another (holding a newline)? Would any problems arise there?

Comment: When I have a character that I know is a newline for sure (dec 10), I place it into the string stream, take it out into a string, and concatenate with another string. Then when I check the length of the final string, it doesn't include the +1 length of the newline. Or it shouldn't?

Comment: @DillPixel In C++, a character is a character is a character... That means that the compiler or library does not differ between one character or another, it doesn't matter if it's a letter, a digit, a space or a newline. If you concatenate two strings, it doesn't matter if they contain newlines or not, the resulting string should contain _all_ characters in both strings.

Comment: Ok this all sounds great, but I'm still having the same problem. Can you take a look at the original post again? (added code)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you test it?

```
    > cat temp.cc
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

string str="vijay\n";

cout << str <<"this is the next line"<<endl;

return 0;
}

    > ./a.out
    vijay
    this is the next line
    >
```

Comment: This is not what I mean. It has to involve a stringstream. See original post.